# removing parenthesis from elements in list

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I have not done regex. I am trying to get rid of '(' and ')' from elements in a list. I tried the following but it does not work.

```
def trial(st):
    a=st.split()
    ls=[]
    for item in a:
        ls.append(item.replace('(',''))
    return a

>>>trial("(   +(       + 8        7)(    + 2 5     ))")   
['(', '+(', '+', '8', '7)(', '+', '2', '5', '))']
```

I am trying to get the following:

```
>>>trial("(   +(       + 8        7)(    + 2 5     ))")   
['+', '+', '8', '7', '+', '2', '5']
```

Comment: It's as simple as `yourstring.replace("("," ").replace(")"," ").split()`... But can I ask what is this for?

Comment: I am evaluating this expression to get 22.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go. Use a stack. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation

Comment: Thank you for showing me the right way. But I have already got a working code. My algorithm is very similar to what the article is talking about, though. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not remove the parentheses first?

```
a = st.replace("("," ").replace(")"," ").split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is quite usefull here:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "(   +(       + 8        7)(    + 2 5     ))"
>>> re.findall("[+0-9]+",s)
['+', '+', '8', '7', '+', '2', '5']
```

if you dont have studied regex:

```
>>> [x for x in s if x=='+' or x.isdigit()]
['+', '+', '8', '7', '+', '2', '5']
```

str.isdigit() will check is the string is digit or not

Comment: Second version assumes single-digit numbers

Comment: @ScottHunter yes for single digit